# How to show json in laravel

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-blade

So I want to show post in data table but there is 2 layer of data, the data it look like this

```
 [
    {
    created_at":
    "id_post":1,
    "name":"trying post",
    "comment_all":
    [
    {
    "id_user":3,
    }
    ],
```

So I want to get comment_all, I use this code in blade

```
@foreach($compalls as $compall )
        <tr>
        <td>{{ $compall->coment_all->id_user }}</td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

but I got this error

> Property [id_user] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: directory/file.blade.php)

hope you can help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `coment_all` is an array. You have to loop through the array to retrieve each `id_user`:

```
@foreach ($compalls as $compall)
    <tr>
        @foreach ($compall->coment_all as $coment)
            <td>{{ $coment->id_user }}</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: @AyamGeprek You are not doing it write. It should be `$compall->coment_all`, not `$compalls->coment_all`.

Comment: @AyamGeprek Take a look at my updated answer. It should be like this. There's **two** foreach loop.

Comment: @AyamGeprek No problem, please mark my answer as the correct one when you can. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop `coment_all` because it is an array. like the following:

First foreach `$compalls` and another foreach inside that to get `id_user`.

```
@foreach ($compalls as $compall)
    <tr>
        @foreach ($compall->coment_all as $coment)
            <td>{{ $coment->id_user }}</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```